# Tool to detect and give info of compression method

Tags: compression, utilities

What is utility tool to detect and give info of compression method (preferably more info) in any mean (CL or GUI) ?

IOW what windows 7z tool equivalent for Linux, giving info easily in GUI?

Comment: "what windows 7z tool equivalent for Linux" – There is `7z` for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has two versions of 7z (both - console utilities with no GUI):

- [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) which has long been unsupported and barely developed

and

- [7zz](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/9f5b067368/) by Igor Pavlov - not that many distros include it, only Arch does as far as I know but you can always compile the sources

Answer (score 0):

Many compression tools are also archivers that can pack multiple files into one. Tools that deal with multiple compression formats almost always deal with archiving as well, and are usually described as *archive*-related tools. So search for “archive” software rather than “compression” software.

The [`file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) displays some basic information about a file's format. It supports most common formats, including compression formats.

```
$ file example.*
example.7z:      7-zip archive data, version 0.4
example.tgz:     gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 10240
example.txt:     ASCII text, with very long lines
example.txt.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
example.txt.gz:  gzip compressed data, was "example.txt", last modified: Wed Oct 27 17:07:19 2021, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 446
example.txt.xz:  XZ compressed data
example.zip:     Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Most archive formats have their own command line tool. [P7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) is available from most distributions and supports common archive formats. It's a port of the `7z` tool available on Windows.

```
$ 7z l -slt example.tgz

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz (806E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 403 bytes (1 KiB)

Listing archive: example.tgz

--
Path = example.tgz
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 10

----------
Path = example.tar
Size = 10240
Packed Size = 403
Modified = 
Host OS = Unix
CRC = E1E368AF
```

Most GUI file managers will display some basic information about compressed files in the file's properties dialog. (The exact name of that dialog depends varies.)

There are a number of GUI tools dedicated to archive processing, which can easily display or extract the content of a single compressed file or a (typically compressed) archive. For example: [File Roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/) (Gnome), [Xarchiver](https://github.com/ib/xarchiver) (Gtk, Xfce, LXDE), [Ark](https://utils.kde.org/projects/ark/) (KDE), …